# UIAccessibility - Trigger for element creation

Tags: ios, swift, uiaccessibility

Is there a way to make a trigger (in Swift) that fires and does something whenever a certain element (like when `app.staticTexts["sometitle"]`) exists and is accessible by Accessibility. In other languages, "stand-by" loops are considered bad practice, so there are latches and callbacks (on creation). Is there something similar in Swift?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Could you explain what you are trying to use this to do?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Let's say, I want to do XCUITest tests, and I have a dynamically added view (ie added and then removed) with a textfield in it. I want a certain method to fire when that view is added.

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly what you're looking for, `UIView` provides a pair of methods, `-willMoveToWindow` and `-didMoveToWindow:`, that might serve your purposes. Working from the other end, you might consider implementing `-didAddSubview:` on the containing view or window. For more information, refer to the [documentation for UIView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class).